# Подключение АЦП AD7705 к stm32

Tags: stm32

Имеется задача снимать показания с тензодатчика с помощью АЦП AD7705, установленный на китайском модуле, и через SPI передавать на stm32f407 (отладочная плата Discovery). Использую библиотеку HAL. Проблема заключается в том, что АЦП, первые несколько измерений передает числа, хоть и чуть "плавующие", но непохожие на реальный вес, а потом вообще передает только одно число. Код, скрины приведены ниже. Многое для своего проекта подчерпнул вот отсюда (http://www.openedv.com/thread-16025-1-1.html), с той лишь разницей, что у меня примерно такой же код не робит.

Настройка SPI на stm32. Системная частота 168 МГц.

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Используемые функции:

```
#define DRDY HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_5)
uint8_t a;

uint8_t SPI1SendByte(uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t rxdata;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CE_GPIO_Port,CE_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1,&data,&rxdata,1,100);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CE_GPIO_Port,CE_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    return rxdata;
}
uint16_t AD7705_ReadData(void){
    uint8_t dataH=0;
    uint8_t dataL=0;
    uint8_t byte=0;
    SPI1SendByte(0x38);
    while(DRDY==1){};
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CE_GPIO_Port,CE_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for(a=0;a<30;a++){};
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1,&byte,&dataH,1,100);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1,&byte,&dataL,1,100);
    for(a=0;a<50;a++){};
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CE_GPIO_Port,CE_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    return (dataH<<8)+dataL;
}
void AD7705_init(void){
    SPI1SendByte(0x20);
    SPI1SendByte(0x0C);
    SPI1SendByte(0x10);
    SPI1SendByte(0x70);
    while(DRDY==1){};
}
```

Код в main.c

```
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<100;i++) //Такое зачем то есть в том примере
  {
        SPI1SendByte(0xff);
    }  
    HAL_Delay(1);
    AD7705_init();
    HAL_Delay(1);   
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

    W=AD7705_ReadData();
    HAL_Delay(100);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Процесс инициализации
[image: Процесс инициализации]
Одно из "плавающих значений"
[image: Одно из "плавающих значений"]
Значение которое всё время повторяется
[image: Значение которое всё время повторяется]

Comment: Почему вы сами устанавливаете вывод Chip Select (Slave Select)? Он находится под управлением периферийного модуля SPI, поэтому его надо инициализировать в режиме альтернативной функции. Тогда низкий уровень на эту линию будет выдаваться периферийным модулем именно в те моменты, когда это необходимо. На ваших диаграммах я сейчас вижу странное поведение этой линии.

Comment: Да знаю, что пином CE можно модулем управлять, хотя и "в ручном" управлении ошибки большой ведь нет. Я вроде разобрался в чём дело. Как только удостоверюсь в этом, опубликую "ответ на собственный вопрос".

Comment: Ошибка есть. Когда вы вручную устанавливаете CE, вы проводите операцию "чтение-модификация-запись", которая неатомарна. Во время её проведения может произойти смена контекста (прерывание, переключение задачи), и в результате у вас время между установкой нового значения CE и началом передачи данных каждый раз разное. Они могут и перекрыться. Во всяком случае, я сталкивался с проблемами при ручном управлении этой линией. Лучше перевести её под управление периферийного модуля SPI.

Comment: Линия должна переходить в высокий уровень каждый раз после завершения приема-передачи. У вас этого нет.

Answer (score 1):

Взял пример отсюда http://read.pudn.com/downloads716/sourcecode/embedded/2868951/AD7705/ad7705.c__.htm заменил AD7705_WriteByte(0x01); на AD7705_WriteByte(0x0C); и AD7705_WriteByte(0x06); на AD7705_WriteByte(0x0C); соответственно все заработало.